# PLSQL REGEX extract a string between two of the same delimiters when the delimiter is inside the string

Tags: regex, plsql, substring

I need a REGEX expression in PLSQL that will extract a substring from a string that contains the delimiter inside the string 0 to multiple times. The string may not contain the delimiter or it may contain multiple instances of the delimiter. The delimiter in my case is the backslash (/).

For example, for vars:

```
Text1 = 'CALLBACK NUMBER: 999-999-9999 /SEGMENT: DENTAL. ASSOCIATE RESOLUTION:  
 /PARTICIPATION: PAR PER PROVIDER /DATES OF SERVICE: UNCLEAR /TOOTH HISTORY GIVEN: YES 
/BENEFITS NEEDED: N/A/CLAIM NUMBER: N/A /TRANSFERRED: N/A '

Text2 = 'CALLBACK NUMBER: 999-999-9999 /SEGMENT: DENTAL. ASSOCIATE RESOLUTION:  
 /PARTICIPATION: PAR PER PROVIDER /DATES OF SERVICE: 12/22/2021 /TOOTH HISTORY GIVEN: YES 
/BENEFITS NEEDED: N/A/CLAIM NUMBER: N/A /TRANSFERRED: N/A '

Text3 = 'CALLBACK NUMBER: 999-999-9999 /SEGMENT: DENTAL. ASSOCIATE RESOLUTION:  
 /PARTICIPATION: PAR PER PROVIDER /DATES OF SERVICE: 12/22/2021, 3/5/2022 /TOOTH HISTORY 
GIVEN: YES /BENEFITS NEEDED: N/A/CLAIM NUMBER: N/A /TRANSFERRED: N/A '
```

the desired result:

```
Text1_result = 'Unclear'
Text2_result = '12/25/2021'
Text3_result = '12/25/2021, 3/5/2022'
```

I used REGEXP_SUBSTR to extract the info this far but I'm having trouble creating a function that can handle multiple instances of the delimiter INSIDE the string its delimiting

EDIT: updated text inputs. Also, the field names behind the DATES OF SERVICE field will not be constant. So I can't delimit it on 'TOOTH' either.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you need to provide some more realistic examples because, from the current examples in your question, it appears that you want the part of the string that comes after `Dates of service: ` up to `/abc`. That would be: `Dates of service: (.+) /abc`

Comment: @Abra I have updated it to the actual strings I'm parsing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments: divide the strings into 3 groups:

- Everything up to '/DATES OF SERVICE: '
- what you want to extract
- Evertything including and after ' /TOOTH HISTORY'

use `REGEXP_REPLACE` backreference to only display the 2nd group:

```
WITH test_data (s) AS
(
SELECT 'CALLBACK NUMBER: 999-999-9999 /SEGMENT: DENTAL. ASSOCIATE RESOLUTION: /PARTICIPATION: PAR PER PROVIDER /DATES OF SERVICE: UNCLEAR /TOOTH HISTORY GIVEN: YES /BENEFITS NEEDED: N/A/CLAIM NUMBER: N/A /TRANSFERRED: N/A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CALLBACK NUMBER: 999-999-9999 /SEGMENT: DENTAL. ASSOCIATE RESOLUTION: /PARTICIPATION: PAR PER PROVIDER /DATES OF SERVICE: 12/22/2021 /TOOTH HISTORY GIVEN: YES /BENEFITS NEEDED: N/A/CLAIM NUMBER: N/A /TRANSFERRED: N/A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CALLBACK NUMBER: 999-999-9999 /SEGMENT: DENTAL. ASSOCIATE RESOLUTION: /PARTICIPATION: PAR PER PROVIDER /DATES OF SERVICE: 12/22/2021, 3/5/2022 /TOOTH HISTORY GIVEN: YES /BENEFITS NEEDED: N/A/CLAIM NUMBER: N/A /TRANSFERRED: N/A ' FROM DUAL
)
select 
  REGEXP_REPLACE(
    s
    ,'^(.*/DATES OF SERVICE: )(.+)( /TOOTH HISTORY.+)'
    ,'\2')
  from test_data;


Unclear
12/25/2021 
12/25/2021, 3/5/2022
```

Adjust to your actual code as needed.

--update--

To allow for other strings than "/TOOTH", the following change is needed. It makes the second subexpression non-greedy and in the third expression checks for a single whitespace, followed by a forward slash and then any character:

```
select 
  REGEXP_REPLACE(
    s
    ,'^(.*/DATES OF SERVICE: )(.+?)([[:space:]]{1}/.*)'
    ,'\2')   
  from test_data;
```

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question to the actual strings I'm parsing as this code returned blank.

Comment: Updated. Read the explanation - the goal is for you to learn how to use this code, not for me to solve your business problem

Comment: AS specified in the edit of the question, the string is not always delimited by /TOOTH HISTORY. Therefore, I can't specify an ending string with alphanumeric characters. Only the backslash. And when I remove "TOOTH HISTORY" from your code, it returns the entire string. Furthermore, if the point is to learn the code you should've specified how you did it, not just what you did. What is the \2 in your REPLACE function? The question is looking for a substring, what are you replacing? Why does removing the alphanumeric characters at the end of the REGEX function change the result?

Comment: I explained that \2 is a backreference to the 2nd group - that is pretty well documented. Let me check if I can find stopping on the backslash. Just a backslash is not possible since that is also there in the dates - how will the regex know it's not a date ? What are the possible values after the backslash instead of just /TOOTH ?

Comment: That works. There is always a space at the end of the string so it will always be a valid form. Thank you.